# How to display List contents in FormView

Tags: c#, .net, formview

I have a `WCF Service` with a method that returns a `List of strings` basically the names of authors and I want to map this data source to `FormView` however I get the following output `System.String[]` as there are more than one authors.

How can I tell `FormView` to take the List and group elements in a string by `,`.

```
    [DataContract]
public class PublicationDetail
{
    [DataMember]
    public string PubID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> Authors { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime PubDate { get; set; }
}



        <ItemTemplate>
            ExtensionData:
            <asp:Label ID="ExtensionDataLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ExtensionData") %>' />
            <br />
            Authors:
            <asp:Label ID="AuthorsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Authors") %>' />
            <br />
            Description:
            <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' />
            <br />
            PubDate:
            <asp:Label ID="PubDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PubDate") %>' />
            <br />
            PubID:
            <asp:Label ID="PubIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PubID") %>' />
            <br />
            Publisher:
            <asp:Label ID="PublisherLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Publisher") %>' />
            <br />
            Title:
            <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' />
            <br />

        </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I made it so it points out what the issue is. I still have not figured out how to fix it Cokhan Coban came pretty close but i still get compile errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your statement as below:

```
Authors:
<asp:Panel ID="pnAddTransition" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:Label ID="AuthorsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Join( ",", ((List<string>)Eval("Authors")).ToArray()) %>' />
<br />
```

Comment: Yields Compiler Error Message: CS0305: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments.  Would Bind need to be outside String.Join ?

Comment: Updated the answer, can you check again?

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

Comment: I added the missing ")" however i get  CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PublicationDetail' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @kellax Can you check last time? :)

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.

Comment: You shouldn't need the cast or the ToArray. It's clearly already an array. Try `String.Join(",", Eval("Authors"))`

Comment: I changed to that so i have <asp:Label ID="AuthorsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Join(",", Eval("Authors")) %>' /> and it outputs System.String[]